# Url rewriting but keeping PHP backend the same?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Let's say I have this URL:
**http://mydomain.com/app/editor/?id=59500**

I would like to have this url to instead show the following in the browser address bar:
**http://mydomain.com/app/editor/59500**

...but have the PHP page ("http://mydomain.com/app/editor/index.php") remain the same. In otherwords, I still want to have this page to be able to execute $_GET['id']; and return "59500".

Would I use regex in HTACCESS for this? Any advice on the best approach and an example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a .htaccess rewrite for this. You can make the redirect happen only when the URL ends with a number (to avoid redirecting index.php).

The `\d+` gets all digits, and the `/?` will allow URLS that either have a slash after the ID or not.

Something like:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteRule ^app/editor/(\d+)(/?)$ app/editor/index.php?id=$1
</ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in the `/app/editor/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/editor/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+app/editor/(index\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index\.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jon Lin but I preferred the simplicity of @Andrew Webb's solution